# Cafe Order Checker in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

Given all three vectors, write a function to check that my service is first-come, first-served. All food should come out in the same order customers requested it.

```
   bool isFirstComeFirstServed(const vector<int>& takeOutOrders,
                                    const vector<int>& dineInOrders,
                                    const vector<int>& servedOrders)


   {
        auto takeOutOrdersIter = takeOutOrders.cbegin();
        auto dineInOrdersIter = dineInOrders.cbegin();

        for (int order : servedOrders) {

            // if we still have orders in takeOutOrders
            // and the current order in takeOutOrders is the same
            // as the current order in servedOrders
            if (takeOutOrdersIter != takeOutOrders.cend() && order == *takeOutOrdersIter) {
                ++takeOutOrdersIter;
            }

            // if we still have orders in dineInOrders
            // and the current order in dineInOrders is the same
            // as the current order in servedOrders
            else if (dineInOrdersIter != dineInOrders.cend() && order == *dineInOrdersIter) {
                ++dineInOrdersIter;
            }

            // if the current order in servedOrders doesn't match the current
            // order in takeOutOrders or dineInOrders, then we're not serving first-come,
            // first-served
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // check for any extra orders at the end of takeOutOrders or dineInOrders
        if (dineInOrdersIter != dineInOrders.cend() || takeOutOrdersIter != takeOutOrders.cend()) {
            return false;
        }

        // all orders in servedOrders have been "accounted for"
        // so we're serving first-come, first-served!
        return true;
    }
```

My doubt is that I've to check that if this solution works for potential repeat element or order, I have check various cases of duplication and solution is working. What do you think? I want to be 100%  sure. Please guide me if there is any flaw there.

Source: https://www.interviewcake.com/question/python/cafe-order-checker?course=fc1&section=array-and-string-manipulation

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this code?

Comment: I want to ask that does this code work on Repeated elements?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it works for cases i tried but how can i be sure that it will work for all the cases in the universe which contain repeated or duplicate elements?